# Unable to locate live website page on server

Tags: drupal, path

I'm working with this page: www.parkinson.org/blog and while the page is live, I'm unable to find where it is housed on the server. The CMS for the website is Drupal, although there is no node for the page, so it could be a standalone page. I'm also unable to find the type of page this would be- .php, for example, which I thought would assist. Is is possible to find a direct path from page source (a baseurl?)? Any tricks working with Internet Information Services (ISS)- tried to search through there but didn't seem to work, either. Lots of questions, any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you have access to the server filesystem? If so, what folders do you see?

Comment: I have direct access to the server itself- the (full) pathway I've been using to edit some other pieces has been C:\inetpub\wwwroot. Folders I have are _files for updating, aspnet_client, includes, misc, modules, phpmyadmin, profiles, rootbackup, scripts, sites, themes, and drupal.

Comment: The main folder of your drupal installation should contain the following folders: includes, misc, modules, profiles, scripts, sites, and themes, and a number of files such as install.php, index.php, ... Is there any folder with these characteristics?

Comment: In C:\inetpub\wwwroot I do have all of those folders and files

Comment: It seems there is a Drupal instance installed in a folder of another Drupal instance (both www.parkinson.org and www.parkinson.org/blog seem  to be Drupal sites). Could you please check if there is a Drupal structure inside the folder "Drupal" you mentioned before?

Comment: I appreciate your help! So I'm trying to understand, and came across this should it make any sense. On C:\drupal there is a series of folders, though they are all empty (sites>default>files>backup), and don't think they are relevant.

Next that I found is:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\drupal

I do not seem to find any other instances. Can you explain how you are seeing the second instance?

Comment: I am accessing www.parkinson.org and www.parkinson.org/blog and both of them seem to be drupal instances.

Comment: Parkinson.org definitely is, and I believe the blog should be- but I'm not sure they would be different. Can you explain what you are looking at in page source or via another means?

Comment: Given a Drupal site installed in url example.com, the login url is usually placed at  example.com/?q=user/login.   I have checked both http://www.parkinson.org/?q=user/login and http://www.parkinson.org/blog/?q=user/login are existing urls, so maybe they belong to different drupal instances, one of them installed in C:\inetpub\wwwroot (main site) and the other one in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ drupal (blog site).

Comment: Thank you, this is a great starting point.

Comment: In this case I discovered that blog was not an actual single page or file since Drupal 7 does not function like this. The method used to change the blog name was to go into the navigation menu and change the title, which reflected on the page!